# asp .net mvc 4 и visual studio 2015 install

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Здравствуйте. Я недавно начал изучать веб технологию и смотрю там нету mvc 4 для работы. Подскажите пожалуйста откуда можно скачать asp .net mvc 4. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Используйте MVC5

Comment: у меня только mvc уставлено, остальные версии нету. Если есть ссылка можете мне написать. Заранее буду благодарен

Comment: В окне New Project что у вас есть, если выбрать Installed - Visual C# - Web ?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JacquesEloff.MicrosoftASPNETWebFrameworksandTools2015

Comment: Спасибо большое. Сам разобрался. Просто 2 дня температура была у меня